# Indexable Types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface NumberDictionary{
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number; //ok, length is a number
    name: string;   //error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

I can't understand why this name can't be string...

Comment: Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide? Your question is not currently in a form that will get much of a response

Comment: Hello guy with a difficult name! It's great you're using SO, but for people to be able to help you we need more information. As stated above by Spangan, read the guide on how to ask a question. Please edit the question with the following: - What is the problem? - What have you tried? - What was the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow what other contributors above have written.

That being said, you've already declared computed property `[index: string]: number`, which basically means that every string variable from now on will be type `number`. Second line doesn't give you an error because you've just said that explicit property named `length` is also a `number`. And in the last line you've said that property `name` is type `string`, which is incorrect since in the first line you've said that all future variables will be `number`.